# Cannot reenable IAM service accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform

we are trying to re-enable some service accounts that were passed to inactive state without reason. After clicked to re-enable it thoughts this error

[image]
and in the request sends this error but i have the ownership of the account, there is no other account managing those accounts.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please update your question with error messages in English instead of using screenshots.

Comment: Also include details on what services/service accounts you are working with.